# Filter data inside map and return content only if is set to "true"

Tags: reactjs

How can I filter my data array and display through map only if the array item is set to "true".

I want to display content if the value is set to TRUE only. **consult__availlability: true**

```
 {filteredConsult &&
            filteredConsult.map((value, i) => {
                const {
                    consult__date: date,
                    consult__time: time,
                    consult__availlability: is_available,
                } = value;
                return (
                    <section key={i}>
                        <div
                            className="consult__results"
                            style={{ marginTop: '2rem' }}>
                            <label>
                                {is_available && (
                                    <div>
                                        <input
                                            type="radio"
                                            id="appointment"
                                            name="appointment"
                                            required="required"
                                            value={value.consultation_date}
                                            onChange={props.handleChange}
                                            disabled={props.disabled}
                                        />
                                        {date}
                                        {time}
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </label>
                            {/* {console.log(props.dateSelect)} */}

                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    </section>
                );
            })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain functions together. First use the `filter` function on the array to have the desired data then use the `map` to have the data in a desired form.

```js
filteredConsult
  .filter(item => item.consult__availlability)
  .map((value, i) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: @NinoMerdzanovic, this way one unnecessery loop will be done, first answer is better

Comment: @DmitryReutov Why should this be a problem? The code is clear and concise and the looping itself is very cheap. I think you are way too much concerned about premature optimization. There will be absolutely no performance problem with this code given a reasonable amount of elements.

Comment: @trixn, i qould not say a word if this answer would be the only one, but TS rejected one, which requires less code and less  execution time, so it looked strange, otherwise no problems at all

Comment: @DmitryReutov How do you know, yours requires less execution time? Did you benchmark it? Are you aware that react will also handle `null` children at least in that it has to look at them and decide not to render it? This is at least one function call and check for `null` for each item that shouldn't be rendered to begin with. And also less code is not equal better code. To chain `filter`/`map`/`reduce` is a common pattern and whole frameworks are built heavily using this approach. There is no performance problem with it and it is clean and concise.

Comment: @trixn, "it has to look at them and decide not to render it"
It has to look at them and decide anyway, so there's no difference if we have it or not, but extra loop is always takes time... may be not if browser's developers are smart enough to join it together

Comment: @DmitryReutov No it doesn't have to look at them if you filter them out beforehand as in the answer. There will be no `null` childs in that case. You may do a little bit of "extra" looping but you save the handling of `null` children by react from which you don't even know the overhead. So it's just a wild guess that execution time will be longer. But all that is still neglectible as the execution time will be very low in both cases. What you do is premature optimisation where no optimisation is required.

Comment: @trixin, Yes, there will be no null childs in that case and react knows it beforehand and doesnt check =)

Comment: @DmitryReutov How does react know beforehand which children it gets? It will still have to check if the child is one of `null`, `true`, `false` or `undefined` for every child and then decide if there is something to render based on that.

Comment: @trixin it was sarcazm, of course it can not and should check anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
return ( consult__availlability ? <section>...<section> : null )
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that. But it retuns all the data which is set to FALSE to. I want to filter before i map the data.

Comment: @NinoMerdzanovic, that is not possible, then please check `consult__availlability` is `boolean` or `string`? if `string` then  need to change it to : `consult__availlability === 'true'` OR `consult__availlability === 'TRUE'` which ever is stored

Comment: @NinoMerdzanovic, `filter` and `map`, it will loop through your data twice, 1 for filter and 2nd for map

Comment: @VivekDoshi What is the problem with looping through it twice (Not quite twice as the second time it will loop though fewer elements)? The proposed solution also has some overhead as react will also look at the children that are `null` which is at least one additional function call and check for `null` but it may be even more depending on how react treats `null` children.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you did it above, through ampersand

```
return is_available && <section
```

or you can filter in advance

```
filteredConsult.filter(v => v.consult__availlability).map((value, i) => {
```

but second option will unnecesserily make one extra loop